# Windows installation Noetic

Tags: windows, ros-noetic

I try to install ROS on Windows using that instruction:

```
https://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows
```

When I had to install  Windows Package Manager I get that error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"
Accès refusé.
```

I executed the command prompt as admin:

[image]

Comment: To get better answers to this, I would recommend that you take a look at help for Windows: 'access denied' is not a ROS error, it's an operating systems permissions error. There's nothing to do with ROS here.

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... copy the text and paste it into your question ... use the `edit` button ... format the text as code